# How to download only the Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have Android Studio installed. Just cleared 3GB Junk memory. So, I want to install full SDK(including All the tools, emulator and not just command line tools as given in "How do I download the Android SDK without downloading Android Studio?") Can I download SDK on mobile and then transfer it to Computer due to some ISP Problem. I have Windows 7 32- bit Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

you can download all seperately from the above original source